# getLongLivedSession in Facebook PHP SDK 5.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

In Facebook PHP SDK 4.0 you can get a LongLivedSession for a user and get the access token for it. With this token you have access to the users account for more than just a few hours.

```
$session = new FacebookSession("[normal access token]");
$longLivedSession = $session->getLongLivedSession("[appID]", "[appSecret]");
$longLivedAccessToken = $longLivedSession->getToken();
```

Facebook\FacebookSession was removed after 4.0 and I need features from the class Facebook\Facebook which was added in 5.0.
Right now I can't find a way to get a longLivedAccesToken in 5.0. Is this because I'm looking for something which doesn't exist or is there a way to do this in 5.0?

As a workaround I would use one controller with 4.0 and one with 5.0 in my app, but it would be really nice if I could avoid that, because that would be really messy.

Comment: i got an example in my latest blogpost: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-5-tutorial/ - and what CBroe answered, of course.

Answer (score 2):

That has been moved to the `Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client` class now.

If you look at the source code of that class, [beginning with line #169](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/5.0-dev/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php#L169) you’ll find:

```
169    /**
170      * Exchanges a short-lived access token with a long-lived access token.
171      *
172      * @param AccessToken|string $accessToken
173      *
174      * @return AccessToken
175      *
176      * @throws FacebookSDKException
177      */
178     public function getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken)
179     {
```

(The documentation does not seem to be fully up to date right now, so in situations like this it is always recommendable that you have a little look around in the source code yourself to see what methods are available and what parameters they take.)

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful.
I think I would have searched for a long time bofore finding it out by myself.